# Nextflow - Google Batch Network options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nextflow, google-batch

I have a Nextflow pipeline running on Google Batch. The process steps will be writing to a serverless Mongo DB Atlas instance. If I add 0.0.0.0/0 to the IP Access list of my Mongo instance, data is written. This tells me the pipeline is working. If I remove 0.0.0.0/0 from the IP Access List, I get SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR.

The question is how do I configure Google Batch to use a Static IP Address with Nextflow ?

I have created a static IP address and Cloud NAT to route traffic to the external static IP address on the same network Nextflow is using.
I tested this be creating a VM without an External IP on the same network Nextflow is using. I ran w3m -dump whatismyip.akamai.com and I get the expected external static IP address.

However, the VM's created by Nextflow (docker hosts ?) have Ephemeral external addresses. I think this is causing the external address to not be the specified static address.

How can I configure Nextflow to run the Google Batch instances useing the "--no-external-ip-address" flag as decribed: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/batch/jobs/submit

Comment: Have you tried using [containerOptions](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-containeroptions) to add that flag?